# JQuery. Скорость движения элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот допустим элемент движется слева страницы на право. Без проблем можно задать скорость выполнения анимации. А как задать скорость этому элементу? Т.е. чтобы он проходил, например 50px в секунду и так пока не досигнет правой стороны страницы

Comment: @inferusvv, без примера кода анимации мы можем только гадание на кофейной гуще устроить.

Comment: А какой должен быть пример? Ну вот например элемент расположен left: 0; делаем анимашку $('#foo').animate({'left', 500} ,1000);

Тут получается, что анимация будет выполнятся 1000 мс. А если задать left не 500px, а 800, то скорость движения элемента будет больше, а скорость самой анимации будет все еще 1000. Как сделать наоборот, чтобы задать скорость, а время выполнения, чтобы "как получится"

Comment: https://github.com/lukeshumard/supremation

Comment: @eicto За плагин спасибо. Вот прям то, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно посчитать длину пути и скорость анимации задать в соответствии с ней.